# The ISR 4321 only have two router ports

Tags: router

I have a ISR 4321 Router in my Cisco Packet Tracer, and I added a `NIM-ES2-4` module, but the The NIM-ES2-4 provides four switching ports.

which are `Gig0/1/0` - `Gig0/1/3`. because I want to use the four ports as Router interface to connect four Switches. but the module only provide switchports.

[image]

So, how to solve this problem?

---

I tried use the `no switchport`, but there is no this command.

```
Router(config-if)#no switchport 
% Incomplete command.
```

Comment: Have you tried `no switchport` on the interface configuration?

Comment: I can not, there is no this command. you can see the NIM-ES2-4 module.

Comment: Use jonathanjo's method below, that is your only chance then.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issues. now my question is this?
after creating the vlans on the routers, are we meant to configure the LAN interface on the same router? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way is to put the separate switch ports into different VLANs, then create virtual interfaces.

That is, four configurations like this:

```
interface Gig0/1/0
 switchport access vlan 10
 no ip address

interface Vlan10
 ip address 10.0.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

This works with any router+switch, not just switch modules inside routers, but you have to have a trunk between the router and switch, or several cables.

(Edit: see Andrey's vital comment: you might well need to create the VLANs too, depending on models/versions etc.)

Comment: I would also mention, that probably it will require actual VLAN creation: `#(conf-t) vlan 10`. In some cases devices will create non-existing VLAN right after `switchport access vlan 10`, but sometimes they're not.

Comment: Very good point, updated.

Comment: You could also mention sub-interfaces on a router interface.

Comment: @jonathanjo So, do you mean the Router only use one physical interface, and create multi virtual interfaces?

Comment: @three-blocks yes exactly like that. You use one physical interface and then create SVI's (VLAN) to route instead.

Answer (score 5):

`4-ports non-POE Layer 2 Gigabit Ethernet Switch Network Interface Module (NIM-ES2-4)`

This module provides only Layer-2 support, so you can't use it's interfaces in Layer-3 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add these modules if you want pure layer 3 port.
NIM-1GE-CU-SFP
NIM-2GE-CU-SFP
SM-X-6X1G
SM-X-4X1G-1X10G

You can reference the modules at the link below:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/4000-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/relevant-interfaces-and-modules.html#ethernet-routed-port