# Is there any router port module of the Cisco Packet Tracer Router?

Tags: cisco, router, packet-tracer

In the Cisco Packet Tracer:

[image]

there are a list Routers, you can see such as `4321`, `1941` and so on.

but I tried everyone, there is no one have a module with multi router ports.

there are switching ports, serial ports. or other indifferent module, there is no a router port module.

[image]

Who know how to get a module with the Router ports? I want to have a router with more router ports.

---

**EDIT01**

My Cisco Packet Tracer version is `7.2`.

Comment: [Here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/54733/29556) Jonathanjo proposed a solution on how to use L2 interfaces, creating SVI for routing (L3) purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [Packet Tracer 7.1.1](https://www.packettracernetwork.com/features/cisco-wic-modules.html) there are a couple of possibilities, including 2621 + two WIC-1ENET or one NM-2FE2W:

> **Cisco 2621XM**
>
> The Cisco 2621XM Multiservice Router provides a one-network module slot platform with **two fixed 10/100** (100BASE-TX) Ethernet ports, **two integrated WAN Interface Card (WIC) slots**, and one Advanced Integration Module (AIM) slot.
>
> **NM-2FE2W**
> The NM-2FE2W Module provides **two Fast-Ethernet interfaces** for use with copper media, in addition to two Wan Interface Card expansion slots. Ideal for a wide range of LAN applications, the Fast Ethernet network modules support many internetworking features and standards.
>
> **WIC-1ENET**
> The WIC-1ENET is a single-port 10 Mbps Ethernet interface card, for use with 10BASE-T Ethernet LANs.

What version of Packet Tracer do you have?